# Alter a Redshift View to point to a new table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I've created a simple view in Redshift that is `select * from source_a with no schema binding`. Now I have a new table, `source_b`, that I would like the view to point to instead that has no new columns or datatypes.

How can I repoint the view without dropping permissions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You run the `CREATE` again but include the `OR REPLACE` syntax.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS …
WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING ;
```

You can retrieve the existing view definition with `pg_get_viewdef`.

```sql
SELECT pg_get_viewdef('my_view', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

First off take a look at the create view documentation page - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_VIEW.html

You have made a late-binding view which checks permissions on the tables when executed so you need to make sure you have the correct permissions on that new table - "source_b".  These late-binding views are a the lookup / reference to the tables rather than a predefined link in the database.  You also cannot grant column lever access to a late binding view.  Otherwise permissions work the same as regular views.

To change the view without having to change the permissions on it you will want to use "create or replace view ..." (see link above) to update the definition.  Just remember that the permissions of the new table will matter.